# How to make two joins using django's ORM

Tags: python, django

I'm using the django ORM to make a query like this:

`MyModel.objects.filter(<condition>)`

This comes out to a query like this:

```
SELECT my_model.* FROM my_model WHERE <condition>
```

If I wanted to join another table, I could do this:

`MyModel.objects.select_related('other_table').filter(<condition>)`

which comes out to:

```
SELECT my_model.*, other_table.* FROM my_model
JOIN other_table ON my_model.other_table_id = other_table.id
```

What do I do if I need to make two joins?

If I do something like `MyModel.objects.select_related('other_table', 'one_mode').filter(<condition>)`

I get an error saying that `one_more` is not related to `my_model`. HOWEVER, is `one_more` IS related to `other_table`, the ORM does not detect that.

Basically I 'm trying to do this:

```
SELECT my_model.*, other_table.* FROM my_model
JOIN other_table ON my_model.other_table_id = other_table.id
JOIN one_more ON one_mode.id = other_table.one_mode_id
```

How do I do this?

Comment: If it is related to `other_table`, then you select it with `.select_related('other_table', 'other_table__one_more')`. Note however that you do *not* need to perform a `.select_related(..)` in order to *filter* on it. You can write `MyModel.objects.filter(other_table__one_more__some_field='foo')`.

Comment: can i perform a join purely through using `.filter()`?

Comment: yes, Django's filtering system decodes the expressions, and will make the correct joins,`.select_related(..)`s are used to improve *performance* if you want fast access to these related models you wish to retrieve.

Comment: If I dump out the raw SQL, it looks like there is no join being performed...

Comment: how do you extract the join? You can do this with `print(str(MyModel.objects.filter(other_table__one_more__some_field='value').query))`.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to `JOIN` on the related model, you use **double underscores** (`__`). So if your models are for example:

```
class Foo(models.Model):
    pass

class Bar(models.Model):
    foo = models.ForeignKey(Foo, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

class Qux(models.Model):
    bar = models.ForeignKey(Foo, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    year = models.IntegerField()
```

You can obtain all `Foo`s for which there exists a related `Bar` for which there exists a related `Qux` with `year` is `2019` like:

```
Foo.objects.filter(bar__qux__year=2019)
```

This will the result in a query like:

```
SELECT foo.*
FROM foo
JOIN bar ON bar.foo_id = foo.id
JOIN qux ON qux.bar_id = bar.id
WHERE qux.year = 2019
```

Note that there is *no* need to use `.select_related(..)` or `.prefetch_related(..)` to make queries on related models. These are used to fetch related models as well in the same (or other queries), and thus to boost efficiency. You *can* of course use these as well, but these serve a different purpose than making the related models available for filtering.

Comment: I suppose the issue i have with this is that i need to be able to select the columns of foo, bar, and qux. According to the output django gives me on the query, i need to select_related to get access to other table columns' values

Comment: @dopatraman: not for filtering. The filter will analyze the tables it needs, and make the correct `JOIN`s. As specified at the bottom of the answer.

Comment: But I am not filtering the fields i need to join, i dont see a way around using select_related

Comment: @dopatraman: again, Django selects the tables that are necessary, and makes the correct joins. For example if you have a m2m, then there is even an extra table in the middle. In that case, one can not even express that "hidden" table. As the documentation says (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/db/queries/#lookups-that-span-relationships): "Django offers a powerful and intuitive way to “follow” relationships in lookups, taking care of the SQL JOINs for you automatically, behind the scenes.".

Comment: @dopatraman: well in case you do not need to filter, you still use double underscores, like `MyModel.objects.select_related('table1', 'table1__table2')`. Django will of course block many-to-many relations, since using a select-related on that, is the wrong approach to fetch objects into memory: it would result in a very expensive query, and leave a huge memory footprint.